# Algebraic Data Types in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, enums, union-types

Is it possible to create an Algebraic Data Type in Postgres and then use it as a column type?

For example:

```
CREATE TYPE hoofed AS ENUM('horse', 'goat');

CREATE TYPE monkey AS ENUM('chimp','macaque');

CREATE TYPE ANIMAL AS ENUM(hoofed, monkey);
```

This fails with:

```
syntax error at or near "hoofed"
LINE 1: CREATE TYPE ANIMAL AS ENUM(hoofed, monkey);
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Ultimately what I would then like to be able to do is something like so:

```
CREATE TABLE zoo (
    a ANIMAL,
    name text
);

INSERT INTO zoo(a, name) VALUES('horse', 'bob');
INSERT INTO zoo(a, name) VALUES('macaque', 'jimmy');
```

And for both of the records to be independently valid.

EDIT: @Abihabi87's response below *does* allow me to create, in effect, a product type, but it still does not allow me to create a union type as desired.

Answer (score 5):

You cant create type enum from others enum type:

you can create ANIMAL that like:

```
CREATE TYPE ANIMAL AS (h hoofed,m monkey);
```

Example in use:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table
(
    a ANIMAL
);

INSERT INTO your_table(a) select (select ('horse','macaque')::ANIMAL);
```

Comment: How would I then use that as a column type?

CREATE TABLE example(
  col1 ANIMAL
);

INSERT INTO example(col1) VALUES('horse');

throws an exception:
[ERROR] error: malformed record literal: "horse"

Comment: So this actually creates records like:

 SELECT * FROM your_table;
        a        
-----------------
 (horse,macaque)
(1 row)


What I'm actually after is for both of the following to be independently valid..

        a        
-----------------
 'horse'
        a        
-----------------
'macaque'

I have updated the question for clarity

Comment: I think this is the right answer for bounty award. He deserve it.

Comment: @AsifAli It doesn't answer the original question. The suggested answer doesn't validate data correctly. We'd need postgres to ensure that for any given x::ANIMAL, exactly one field is non null. If that's impossible to ensure in Postgres, then an answer would have to say so in order to address the original question.

Answer (score 4):

With `ENUM` types, you cannot achieve dynamic type composition/union. However, with [`DOMAIN` types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html), you could achieve something similar:

```
create function valid_any_domain(anyelement, variadic regtype[])
  returns boolean
  language plpgsql
  immutable
as $func$
declare
  t regtype;
begin
  foreach t in array $2 loop
    begin
      execute format('select $1::%s', t) using $1;
    exception
      when not_null_violation or check_violation then
        continue;
    end;
    return true;
  end loop;

  return false;
end;
$func$;

create domain hoofed as text
  check (value in ('horse', 'goat'));

create domain monkey as text
  check (value in ('chimp','macaque'));

create domain animal as text
  check (valid_any_domain(value, 'hoofed', 'monkey'));
```

Changing the base types will dynamically change the composite/union type too, but still requires a manual constraint validation (especially, when some value(s) are removed from the valid spectrum):

```
alter domain hoofed drop constraint hoofed_check;
alter domain hoofed add check (value in ('horse', 'goat', 'zebra'));
alter domain animal validate constraint animal_check;
```

http://rextester.com/MBVC62095

*Note*: however, with `DOMAIN` types, you will lose an `ENUM` property: the custom ordering. `DOMAIN`s will always use the underlying type's ordering.

Answer (score 3):

Use the function:

```
create or replace function create_enum(name, variadic regtype[])
returns void language plpgsql as $$
begin
    execute format(
        'create type %I as enum(%s)', 
        $1, 
        string_agg(quote_literal(enumlabel), ',' order by enumtypid, enumsortorder))
    from pg_enum
    where enumtypid = any($2);
end $$;
```

Pass the name of a new type and a list of enum types as arguments:

```
select create_enum('animal', 'hoofed', 'monkey');

select enum_range(null::animal) as animal;

           animal           
----------------------------
 {horse,goat,chimp,macaque}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

Effectively you are trying to merge two `enum` types.
There are some open questions:

- Can there be duplicate strings?
- Is the design supposed to be *static* (changes to `enum` type `hoofed` do not change type `animal` later) or dynamic (the opposite).
- Merge exactly two `enum` types or more?
- Since the order of elements is significant, what is the order of elements in `animal` supposed to be?
- Is this a one-time operation or intended for repeated use?

***Assuming*** no duplicates, static design, two `enum` types, existing order of elements as appended and one-time operation.

You can use the built-in [enum support function `enum_range(anyenum)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-enum.html#FUNCTIONS-ENUM-TABLE) to get an array of all elements for a given `enum` type.

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE (
   SELECT 'CREATE TYPE animal AS ENUM (' 
        || array_to_string(enum_range(null::hoofed)::text[]
                        || enum_range(null::monkey)::text[], ''',''')
        || ''')'
   );
END
$$;
```

Comment: That's actually really cool!

Is it possible for future updates to the underlying ENUM to update the new ENUM dynamically?

Comment: @AbrahamP: No, that's not possible this way. You can drop and recreate the `animal` type or you can write server-side code to add / remove elements dynamically, but you need to consider dependencies and implications for existing data first.

Comment: @AbrahamP A [DDL event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html) should be able to do that.