# How to change the data type of a table column to enum?

Tags: postgresql, enums, alter-table

I have a table `"ENGINE"` in a Postgres DB, in which I have to change the datatype of a column named `loglevel` from string to enum.

However, I am not able to understand instructions in the manual:

```
ALTER [ COLUMN ] column TYPE type [ USING expression ]
```

Answer (score 5):

[`enum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html) is not a data type per se. It's a *class* of data types. (Generally, you can replace any `enum` with a FK column to a 1:n table.) And "string" is not a data type at all in Postgres. I assume we are talking about `text` or `varchar`? If so, these are the steps for your task:

#### Step 1

Create new `enum` type if it does not exist, yet.

Let's call it `loglevel`. It has to include all distinct values from your string column or the type cast will fail. This `DO` command takes care of it:

```sql
DO
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE (
   SELECT 'CREATE TYPE loglevel AS ENUM (' 
        || string_agg(quote_literal(loglevel), ', ')
        || ')'
   FROM  (
      SELECT loglevel
      FROM   "ENGINE"
      WHERE  loglevel IS NOT NULL  -- exclude NULL if present
      GROUP  BY 1
      ORDER  BY 1
      ) sub
   );
END
$$;
```

We have to exclude NULL if present, that cannot be listed as enum value. (Any `enum` type can be NULL anyway.)

Related:

- [Algebraic Data Types in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431740/algebraic-data-types-in-postgres/44488340#44488340)

#### Step 2

Change the data type of the column:

You have to specify `USING loglevel::loglevel` explicitely, since there is no implicit cast between any string type (`text`, `varchar`, ...) and the new `enum` data type:

```
ALTER TABLE "ENGINE" ALTER loglevel TYPE loglevel USING loglevel::loglevel;
```

Details:

- [Rails Migrations: tried to change the type of column from string to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343383/rails-migrations-tried-to-change-the-type-of-column-from-string-to-integer/10343444#10343444)

Comment: What's the syntax in the USING clause? Is it `USING column::new_type`?

Comment: @TheHoff: Yes, `USING loglevel::loglevel` implements `USING column::new_type` here.