# Sort by given "rank" of column values

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a table like this (**unsorted**):

| risk | category |
| --- | --- |
| Low | A |
| Medium | B |
| High | C |
| Medium | A |
| Low | B |
| High | A |
| Low | C |
| Low | E |
| Low | D |
| High | B |

I need to sort rows by `category`, but first based on the value of `risk`. The desired result should look like this (**sorted**):

| risk | category |
| --- | --- |
| Low | A |
| Low | B |
| Low | C |
| Low | D |
| Low | E |
| Medium | A |
| Medium | B |
| High | A |
| High | B |
| High | C |

I've come up with below **query** but wonder if it is correct:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    some_table
ORDER BY
    CASE
    WHEN risk = 'Low'    THEN
    0
    WHEN risk = 'Medium' THEN
    1
    WHEN risk = 'High'   THEN
    2
    ELSE
    3
    END,
    category;
```

Just want to understand whether the query is correct or not. The actual data set is huge and there are many other values for risk and categories and hence I can't figure out if the results are correct or not. I've just simplified it here.

Comment: Your query looks correct to me.  Have you tested it?

Comment: Since you write "there are many other values for risk", the question is whether these other values are always these three you used in your case construct? If not and further values are possible, I recommend to create a mapping table with the risk and a number which indicates the order. Then you can join this table and order by the number and you don't need a complex case construct with lots of cases.

Comment: why you using case:if I understand the problem I think you need
select * from table order by risk,category

Comment: @abdalmohaymenaliesmaeel: Because 'High' sorts before 'Medium'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically correct, but you can simplify:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   some_table
ORDER  BY CASE risk
            WHEN 'Low'    THEN 0
            WHEN 'Medium' THEN 1
            WHEN 'High'   THEN 2
            -- rest defaults to NULL and sorts last
          END
        , category;
```

A ["switched" `CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) is shorter and slightly cheaper.
In the absence of an `ELSE` branch, all remaining cases default to NULL, and NULL sorts last in default ascending sort order. So you don't need to do anything extra.

#### Many other values

> ... there are many other values for risk

While all other values are lumped together at the bottom of the sort order, this seems ok.
**If** all of those many values get their individual ranking, I would suggest an additional table to handle ranks of risk values. Like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE riskrank (
  risk text PRIMARY KEY
, riskrank real
);

INSERT INTO riskrank VALUES
  ('Low'   , 0)
, ('Medium', 1)
, ('High'  , 2)
-- many more?
;
```

Data type `real`, so it's easy to squeeze in rows with fractional digits in different positions (like `enum` values do it internally).

Then your query is:

```sql
SELECT s.*
FROM   some_table s
LEFT   JOIN risk_rank rr USING (risk)
ORDER  BY rr.riskrank, s.category;
```

`LEFT JOIN`, so missing entries in `riskrank` don't eliminate rows.

#### `enum`?

I already mentioned the [data type `enum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html). That's a possible alternative as enum values are sorted in the order they are defined (not how they are spelled). They only occupy 4 bytes on disk (`real` internally), are fast and enforce valid values implicitly. See:

- [How to change the data type of a table column to enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936907/how-to-change-the-data-type-of-a-table-column-to-enum/44937403#44937403)

**However**, I would only even consider an enum if the sort order of your values is immutable. Changing sort order and adding / removing allowed values is cumbersome. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html#id-1.5.7.15.8)

> Although enum types are primarily intended for static sets of values,
> there is support for adding new values to an existing enum type, and
> for renaming values (see [`ALTER TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertype.html)). Existing values cannot be
> removed from an enum type, nor can the sort ordering of such values be
> changed, short of dropping and re-creating the enum type.

Comment: Very helpful and thanks for the switched case tip. The number of risk isn’t too big (12 values) so I’d go for Switch case. This all translates back to Java code so don’t want to create another table etc.